# Icons for favorite tags

Tags: script, tags, tampermonkey

I have a lot of tags in my "favorite tags" and it got to the point where they span across like five lines, and it was just too bulky for my liking. So, I made a user-script that replaces the text labels of my favorite tags with much smaller icons. Here's a before and after:

[image: before]
[image: after]

Obviously, the script is not perfect; it has some padding issues, and it's missing a lot of icons that I'd like to eventually add (still haven't figured out how I'm going to represent HTML/CSS without using the HTML5/CSS3 logos). It could also probably eventually be adapted to work on lots of Stack Exchange sites, not just Stack Overflow.

Easiest way to install it is with [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) on Chrome/Opera/etc. Just click the Tampermonkey icon, click "Add a new script...", and paste in the code. It ought to work just as well in Firefox/etc since it's just a Greasemonkey script, but I haven't tested it.

Anyway, enough lollygagging; let's get to the actual code! The script is [on GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/oxguy3/a5f57845616bbe317989), or here:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Overflow tag icons
// @namespace    http://schiff.io
// @version      0.1
// @description  Replace tag names with pretty icons
// @author       Hayden Schiff (oxguy3)
// @match        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// license: CC0 <https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/>

// should the icons apply everywhere tags appear, or just for favorite tags?
// there are a lot of bugs you'll encounter if you turn this on
var SHOULD_APPLY_EVERYWHERE = false;




var tagsSelector = SHOULD_APPLY_EVERYWHERE ? ".post-tag" : "#interestingTags>.post-tag";

// import devicons
$("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
    href: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/devicons/1.8.0/css/devicons.min.css"
}).appendTo("head");

// mapping of StackOverflow tags to devicons icon classes
var tagData = {};

/*tagData["amazon-web-services"] = {
    iconClass: "aws"
};*/

tagData["android"] = {
    iconClass: "android"
};
tagData["android-layout"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "layout"
};
tagData["android-fragments"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "fragments"
};
tagData["android-intent"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "intent"
};
tagData["android-activity"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "activity"
};
tagData["android-listview"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "listview"
};
tagData["android-studio"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "studio"
};
tagData["android-asynctask"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "asynctask"
};
tagData["android-ndk"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "ndk"
};
tagData["android-actionbar"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "actionbar"
};
tagData["android-emulator"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "emulator"
};
tagData["android-edittext"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "edittext"
};
tagData["android-viewpager"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "viewpager"
};
tagData["android-widget"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "widget"
};
tagData["android-webview"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "webview"
};
tagData["android-service"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "service"
};
tagData["android-camera"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "camera"
};
tagData["android-sqlite"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "sqlite"
};
tagData["android-manifest"] = {
    iconClass: "android",
    textSuffix: "manifest"
};

tagData["angularjs"] = {
    iconClass: "angular"
};
tagData["angularjs-directive"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "directive"
};
tagData["angularjs-scope"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "scope"
};
tagData["angularjs-ng-repeat"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "ng-repeat"
};
tagData["angularjs-ui-router"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "ui-router"
};
tagData["angularjs-ui"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "ui"
};
tagData["angularjs-ui-bootstrap"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "ui-bootstrap"
};
tagData["angularjs-service"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "service"
};
tagData["angularjs-routing"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "routing"
};
tagData["angularjs-controller"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "controller"
};
tagData["angularjs-filter"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "filter"
};
tagData["angularjs-dart"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "dart"
};
tagData["angularjs-ui-grid"] = {
    iconClass: "angular",
    textSuffix: "ui-grid"
};

tagData["arrays"] = {
    bigText: "[ ]"
};

tagData["backbone.js"] = {
    iconClass: "backbone"
};

tagData["codeigniter"] = {
    iconClass: "codeigniter"
};
tagData["codeigniter-2"] = {
    iconClass: "codeigniter",
    textSuffix: "2"
};
tagData["codeigniter-3"] = {
    iconClass: "codeigniter",
    textSuffix: "3"
};
tagData["codeigniter-url"] = {
    iconClass: "codeigniter",
    textSuffix: "url"
};
tagData["codeigniter-routing"] = {
    iconClass: "codeigniter",
    textSuffix: "routing"
};

tagData["coffeescript"] = {
    iconClass: "coffeescript"
};

tagData["compass"] = {
    iconClass: "compass"
};
tagData["compass-sass"] = {
    iconClass: "compass"
};

tagData["css3"] = {
    iconClass: "css3_full"
};

tagData["dart"] = {
    iconClass: "dart"
};

tagData["database"] = {
    iconClass: "database"
};

tagData["django"] = {
    iconClass: "django"
};

tagData["drupal"] = {
    iconClass: "drupal"
};

tagData["eclipse"] = {
    iconClass: "eclipse"
};

tagData["firefox"] = {
    iconClass: "firefox"
};

tagData["git"] = {
    iconClass: "git"
};

tagData["github"] = {
    iconClass: "github_badge"
};

tagData["go"] = {
    iconClass: "go"
};

/*tagData["google-app-engine"] = {
    iconClass: "google-cloud-platform"
};*/

tagData["google-chrome"] = {
    iconClass: "chrome"
};
tagData["google-chrome-extension"] = {
    iconClass: "chrome",
    textSuffix: "extensions"
};

/*tagData["grails"] = {
    iconClass: "grails"
};*/

tagData["html5"] = {
    iconClass: "html5"
};

tagData["internet-explorer"] = {
    iconClass: "ie"
};

tagData["java"] = {
    iconClass: "java"
};
tagData["java-ee"] = {
    iconClass: "java",
    textSuffix: "ee"
};

tagData["javascript"] = {
    iconClass: "javascript"
};

tagData["jenkins"] = {
    iconClass: "jenkins"
};

tagData["joomla"] = {
    iconClass: "joomla"
};

tagData["jquery"] = {
    iconClass: "jquery"
};
tagData["jquery-mobile"] = {
    iconClass: "jquery",
    textSuffix: "mobile"
};
tagData["jquery-plugins"] = {
    iconClass: "jquery",
    textSuffix: "plugins"
};
tagData["jquery-selectors"] = {
    iconClass: "jquery",
    textSuffix: "selectors"
};
tagData["jquery-validate"] = {
    iconClass: "jquery",
    textSuffix: "validate"
};
tagData["jquery-animate"] = {
    iconClass: "jquery",
    textSuffix: "animate"
};
tagData["jquery-datatables"] = {
    iconClass: "jquery",
    textSuffix: "datatables"
};

tagData["jquery-ui"] = {
    iconClass: "jquery_ui"
};

tagData["laravel"] = {
    iconClass: "laravel"
};
tagData["laravel-4"] = {
    iconClass: "laravel",
    textSuffix: "4"
};
tagData["laravel-5"] = {
    iconClass: "laravel",
    textSuffix: "5"
};

tagData["less"] = {
    iconClass: "less"
};

tagData["linux"] = {
    iconClass: "linux"
};

tagData["markdown"] = {
    iconClass: "markdown"
};
tagData["github-flavored-markdown"] = {
    iconClass: "markdown",
    textPrefix: "github-flav"
};

tagData["meteor"] = {
    iconClass: "meteor"
};

tagData["modernizr"] = {
    iconClass: "modernizr"
};

tagData["mongodb"] = {
    iconClass: "mongodb"
};
tagData["mongodb-query"] = {
    iconClass: "mongodb",
    textSuffix: "query"
};
tagData["mongodb-csharp"] = {
    iconClass: "mongodb",
    textSuffix: "c#"
};
tagData["mongodb-java"] = {
    iconClass: "mongodb",
    textSuffix: "java"
};
tagData["mongodb-php"] = {
    iconClass: "mongodb",
    textSuffix: "php"
};

tagData["mysql"] = {
    iconClass: "mysql"
};

tagData[".net"] = {
    iconClass: "dotnet"
};

tagData["nginx"] = {
    iconClass: "nginx"
};

tagData["node.js"] = {
    iconClass: "nodejs_small"
};

tagData["php"] = {
    iconClass: "php"
};
tagData["php-5.2"] = {
    iconClass: "php",
    textSuffix: "5.2"
};
tagData["php-5.3"] = {
    iconClass: "php",
    textSuffix: "5.3"
};
tagData["php-5.4"] = {
    iconClass: "php",
    textSuffix: "5.4"
};
tagData["php-5.5"] = {
    iconClass: "php",
    textSuffix: "5.5"
};

tagData["postgresql"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql"
};
tagData["postgresql-8.0"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "8.0"
};
tagData["postgresql-8.1"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "8.1"
};
tagData["postgresql-8.2"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "8.2"
};
tagData["postgresql-8.3"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "8.3"
};
tagData["postgresql-8.4"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "8.4"
};
tagData["postgresql-9.0"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "9.0"
};
tagData["postgresql-9.1"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "9.1"
};
tagData["postgresql-9.2"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "9.2"
};
tagData["postgresql-9.3"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "9.3"
};
tagData["postgresql-9.4"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "9.4"
};
tagData["postgresql-9.5"] = {
    iconClass: "postgresql",
    textSuffix: "9.5"
};

tagData["python"] = {
    iconClass: "python"
};
tagData["python-2.x"] = {
    iconClass: "python",
    textSuffix: "2.x"
};
tagData["python-2.4"] = {
    iconClass: "python",
    textSuffix: "2.4"
};
tagData["python-2.5"] = {
    iconClass: "python",
    textSuffix: "2.5"
};
tagData["python-2.6"] = {
    iconClass: "python",
    textSuffix: "2.6"
};
tagData["python-2.7"] = {
    iconClass: "python",
    textSuffix: "2.7"
};
tagData["python-3.x"] = {
    iconClass: "python",
    textSuffix: "3.x"
};
tagData["python-3.3"] = {
    iconClass: "python",
    textSuffix: "3.3"
};
tagData["python-3.4"] = {
    iconClass: "python",
    textSuffix: "3.4"
};

tagData["regex"] = {
    bigText: ".*"
};

tagData["ruby"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby"
};

tagData["ruby-on-rails"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails"
};
tagData["ruby-on-rails-2"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails",
    textSuffix: "2"
};
tagData["ruby-on-rails-3"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails",
    textSuffix: "3"
};
tagData["ruby-on-rails-3.1"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails",
    textSuffix: "3.1"
};
tagData["ruby-on-rails-3.2"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails",
    textSuffix: "3.2"
};
tagData["ruby-on-rails-4"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails",
    textSuffix: "4"
};
tagData["ruby-on-rails-4.1"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails",
    textSuffix: "4.1"
};
tagData["ruby-on-rails-4.2"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails",
    textSuffix: "4.2"
};
tagData["ruby-on-rails-plugins"] = {
    iconClass: "ruby_on_rails",
    textSuffix: "plugins"
};

tagData["rust"] = {
    iconClass: "rust"
};

tagData["sass"] = {
    iconClass: "sass"
};

tagData["scala"] = {
    iconClass: "scala"
};

/*tagData["sqlite"] = {
    iconClass: "sqllite"
};*/

tagData["swift"] = {
    iconClass: "swift"
};
tagData["swift2"] = {
    iconClass: "swift",
    textSuffix: "2"
};

tagData["symfony2"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge"
};
tagData["symfony1"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "1"
};
tagData["symfony-1.2"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "1.4"
};
tagData["symfony-1.3"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "1.4"
};
tagData["symfony-1.4"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "1.4"
};
tagData["symfony-2.0"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.1"
};
tagData["symfony-2.1"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.0"
};
tagData["symfony-2.2"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.2"
};
tagData["symfony-2.3"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.3"
};
tagData["symfony2.4"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.4"
};
tagData["symfony-2.5"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.5"
};
tagData["symfony-2.6"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.6"
};
tagData["symfony-2.7"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.7"
};
tagData["symfony-2.8"] = {
    iconClass: "symfony_badge",
    textSuffix: "2.8"
};

tagData["twitter-bootstrap"] = {
    iconClass: "bootstrap"
};
tagData["twitter-bootstrap-2"] = {
    iconClass: "bootstrap",
    textSuffix: "2"
};
tagData["twitter-bootstrap-3"] = {
    iconClass: "bootstrap",
    textSuffix: "3"
};
tagData["twitter-bootstrap-4"] = {
    iconClass: "bootstrap",
    textSuffix: "4"
};
tagData["twitter-bootstrap-rails"] = {
    iconClass: "bootstrap",
    textSuffix: "rails"
};

tagData["ubuntu"] = {
    iconClass: "ubuntu"
};

/*tagData["vim"] = {
    iconClass: "vim"
};*/

tagData["visual-studio"] = {
    iconClass: "visualstudio"
};
tagData["visual-studio-2005"] = {
    iconClass: "visualstudio",
    textSuffix: "'05"
};
tagData["visual-studio-2008"] = {
    iconClass: "visualstudio",
    textSuffix: "'08"
};
tagData["visual-studio-2010"] = {
    iconClass: "visualstudio",
    textSuffix: "'10"
};
tagData["visual-studio-2012"] = {
    iconClass: "visualstudio",
    textSuffix: "'12"
};
tagData["visual-studio-2013"] = {
    iconClass: "visualstudio",
    textSuffix: "'13"
};
tagData["visual-studio-2015"] = {
    iconClass: "visualstudio",
    textSuffix: "'15"
};

tagData["windows"] = {
    iconClass: "windows"
};

tagData["wordpress"] = {
    iconClass: "wordpress"
};
tagData["wordpress-plugin"] = {
    iconClass: "wordpress",
    textSuffix: "plugin"
};
tagData["wordpress-plugin-dev"] = {
    iconClass: "wordpress",
    textSuffix: "plugin-dev"
};
tagData["wordpress-theming"] = {
    iconClass: "wordpress",
    textSuffix: "theming"
};



$(tagsSelector).each(function(index){
    var tagName = $(this).text();
    var tag = tagData[tagName];

    if (typeof tag !== 'undefined' && tagName != "constructor" && tagName != "prototype") {
        var newHtml = "";

        if (typeof tag.textPrefix !== 'undefined') {
            newHtml += "<span style='font-size:12px'>" + tag.textPrefix + "</span>&nbsp;";
        }

        if (typeof tag.iconClass !== 'undefined') {
            newHtml += '<span class="devicons devicons-' + tag.iconClass + '"></span>';
        }

        if (typeof tag.bigText !== 'undefined') {
            newHtml += '<span style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; line-height:1;">' + tag.bigText + "</span>";
        }

        if (typeof tag.textSuffix !== 'undefined') {
            newHtml += "&nbsp;<span style='font-size:12px'>" + tag.textSuffix + "</span>";
        }

        $(this).html(newHtml);
        $(this).css("padding", "0.1em 0.2em");
        $(this).css("font-size", "18px");
        $(this).css("height", "20px");
        $(this).css("min-width", "18px");
    }
});
```

Anyway, what do you guys think of this?

DISCLAIMER: don't try to edit your list of favorite tags while this script is enabled; you'll end up losing them.